# How can I reduce network latency for using from recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

thanks for your time. I am using [Azure form recognizer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) of Azure cognitive service. It works well for most of my users. However, for Chinese users, Azure China has not released this product.
So Chinese users must request the Azure global endpoint and the issue comes :
the latency is pretty high, sometimes , it comes out as `5000ms`. So is there anyway to reduce the latency? Or any workaround ?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You could possibly host it in a region close to China (Hong Kong, Singapore, Japan, Korea etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GauravMantri recommended, you could host it in a region close to China.

If it still comes out as high latency, you can try this way that recommended by the Microsoft partner consultant：

1. Deploy an [APIM service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/) in Azure China.
2. Put your Azure global endpoint behind the APIM and expose APIs by APIM. Let your Chinese users access the Azure global endpoint via APIM could greatly reduce the network latency.

I have tried it before and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Stanley! I did a quick test and it do reduce the network latency. Do you know its principle?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Azure Form Recognizer that runs in containers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto

It is marked as "retiring". But maybe you could run it in AKS in China until Azure China has released this product.